# Cakephp: associations of associations in "fields"

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-2.0

a post has a user (belongsTo) and a user has a profile (hasOne). Normally everything works: I can access from Post to User and from User to Profile.

From Post, all works using a generic Find. The result is more or less this (I deleted some keys, just for example):

```
array(
    'Post' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'category_id' => '1',
        'user_id' => '1',
        'title' => 'Example',
        'text' => '',
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'password' => '*****',
        'id' => '1',
        'group_id' => '1',
        'username' => 'mirko',
        'status' => 'active',
        'Profile' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '1',
            'first_name' => 'Mirko',
            'last_name' => 'Pagliai',
        ),
    )
)
```

The problem comes when I use "fields", when I want to extract only a few fields.
For example, this works:

```
'fields'        => array('id', 'title', 'User.id')
```

and the result is:

```
array(
    'Post' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'title' => 'Articolo di prova :-)'
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'id' => '1'
    )
)
```

But I don't understand, always using "fields", how to access Profile.
These don'yt work:

```
'fields'        => array('id', 'title', 'User.id', 'Profile.id')

'fields'        => array('id', 'title', 'User.id', 'User.Profile.id')
```

I always get this error "Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'User.Profile.id' in 'field list'".

What's wrong? Thanks.

EDIT:
I'm not using the Containable behavior. Maybe is this the problem? Is it essential in this case?

An example, using paginate:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions'    => $conditions,
    'fields'        => array('id', 'title', 'User.id', 'Profile.id'),
    'limit'         => 10,
    'recursive'     => 2,
);
```

EDIT2:
thanks to @Hoff, I am close to the solution. But there is still something wrong (and Containable is very useful!).
In AppModel.php I added:

```
...
class AppModel extends Model {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $recursive = -1;
...
```

But this doesn't work:

```
$this->paginate = array(
            'conditions'    => $conditions,
            'contain'       => array(
                'User' => array(
                    'fields' => array('id'),
                    'Profile' => array(
                        'fields' => array('id', 'full_name'),
                    ),
                ),
                'Category' => array(
                    'fields' => 'title',
                ),
            ),
            'fields'        => array('id', 'user_id', 'category_id', 'title', 'created', 'modified', 'published'),
            'limit'         => 10,
        );
```

Cause I get:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Post' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '1',
            'category_id' => '1',
            'title' => 'Articolo di prova :-)',
            'created' => '2012-06-21 18:46:00',
            'modified' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            'published' => true
        ),
        'Category' => array(
            'title' => 'prova',
            'id' => '1'
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '1'
        )
    )
)
```

but if I add any field to User (email, username, password, etc.), this works:

```
            'User' => array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'username'),
                'Profile' => array(
                    'fields' => array('id', 'full_name'),
                ),
            ),
```

And I get:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Post' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '1',
            'category_id' => '1',
            'title' => 'Articolo di prova :-)',
            'created' => '2012-06-21 18:46:00',
            'modified' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            'published' => true
        ),
        'Category' => array(
            'title' => 'prova',
            'id' => '1'
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'username' => 'mirko',
            'Profile' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'full_name' => 'Mirko Pagliai'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can I see your find call? Also, are you using the Containable behavior?

Comment: I answered by editing the first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the 'recursive' key, I highly suggest using the containable behavior. The documentation on the behavior can be found [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html). I would suggest applying the behavior in your AppModel so you don't need to add it to all your models. In Model/AppModel.php:

```
App::uses('Model', 'Model');
class AppModel extends Model {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $recursive = -1;
}
```

Then, for your pagination:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions'    => $conditions,
    'fields'        => array('id', 'title'),
    'limit'         => 10,
    'contain' => array(
        'User' => array(
            'fields' => array('id'),
            'Profile' => array(
                'fields' => array('id')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: This cannot work, cause Post and Profile haven't a direct relation.
In fact I get the error:  
Warning (512): Model "Post" is not associated with model "Profile" [CORE/Cake/Model/Behavior/ContainableBehavior.php, line 339]  
Instead, your example works with User.

Comment: You can nest as many levels deep as you want, see my edit. Sorry I skipped a model! Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks @Hoff, I am close to the solution. But there is still something wrong. Look at my first message (edited), thanks!

Comment: Ohh I see now it's not pulling back Profile. Try including all foreign keys in your 'fields' array as well and see if that works...

Comment: nothing to do. All foreing keys are given, but it only works if I point to at least two user keys (ie if I add a second key any), as I have indicated in the first post.

Comment: I'm at a loss - the only thing I can think of is the important hint in the Containable documentation: "
When using ‘fields’ and ‘contain’ options - be careful to include all foreign keys that your query directly or indirectly requires. Please also note that because Containable must to be attached to all models used in containment, you may consider attaching it to your AppModel."